# Can I reuse Pokemon images from Bulbapedia for making a boot screen theme in Ubuntu?

Tags: copyright, license

I am planning to make a [Plymouth theme](https://wiki.debian.org/plymouth) with some pokemon images (like [this](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/File:0152Chikorita.png)) from [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Main_Page).

I want to release the theme under GPL3.

Bulbapedia's Fair Use [policy](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bulbapedia:Fair_use) seems confusing to me. Under this policy, can I reuse their images, giving due credit to them in the copyright file?

How should I acknowledge these images in the copyright file?

Comment: The answer is written in parentheses on that page: "Bulbapedia does not own the image's copyrights and can therefore not give permission to use them".

Comment: A possible workaround is to design your boot theme without using the copyrighted elements (e.g. use a substitute image instead), and then add a feature which allows the the end-user to easily customize to a different image if she wishes. This is basically what all Desktop themes do. All of them that I've seen come with a default wallpaper image (which is designed and licensed to be included in the system). But all desktop environments include an option to let the user pick her own image (perhaps an unlicensed one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No chance whatsoever.

Those images are copyright Nintendo and friends, and are not released under a free license of any kind. There are only two legal ways you can use the images:

- By obtaining a license from Nintendo
- Under fair use doctrines. This is the basis on which Bulbapedia are using the images, and whether or not that is valid depends on what the images are being used for; you cannot place them under a free license.

  - Personally, I'd say Bulbapedia's fair use claim wouldn't stand up in courts in most jurisdictions but nobody really cares what I think.

Comment: So, does that mean, one cannot use any pokemon images in a software without obtaining license from Nintendo?

Comment: Pretty much yes, that's exactly what copyright is for - to prevent other people copying your work.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Strictly speaking you would also need permission from Creatures Inc and GameFreak, because the Pokémon IP is jointly owned (and possibly also The Pokémon Company and/or Shogakukan depending on where you are in the world and where the images originally came from). In practice though Nintendo would be all you need, since they’re the only ones who really go after violations (and they interestingly only seem to care about violations if you’re making money off of them, even if the derivative works are extremely undesirable for the brand image by most measures).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn the "and friends" in the earlier paragraph was my attempt to cover the complexities of Pokémon licensing :)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi You can use as many pokemon images as you want in your software. You can _not_ distribute that software without a license from Nintendo.

Comment: Using fanart (with the permission of the artists) might be an option. But that's still a grey area, because Nintendo might argue for [character copyright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_protection_for_fictional_characters).

Comment: @Philipp I would honestly be surprised if Nintendo did make such an argument unless a financial transaction took place involving the art. Nintendo is somewhat notorious for not going after fanart, no matter the content, as long as the artist is not making money off of it, but as soon as they learn about an artist making money off of it they get rather aggressive about copyright enforcement (and not just with Pokémon, though that’s arguably the biggest example for a number of reasons).

Comment: Bulbapedia's use of the images is descriptive and helps identify the subject. So it's a strong case for fair use. However, using them in absolutely anything other than an article about that pokemon is clearly not.

Comment: @Therac If Bulbapedia were serious about using the fair-use argument, they'd probably need to switch to using thumbnails-only/lower-res versions on their servers, and to supply the full-res pokémon images only by directly linking them to a licensed server (e.g. using an iframe or another technical trick like that). Courts have ruled that doing it this way is probably fair use. This is what Google Images does, for example (full-res versions are always from the original server). Of course, this method would open up Bulbapedia to being server-blacklisted, at least for the full-res versions.

Comment: @Brandin They could do that, but it's not a condition for fair use. A long time ago, I recall that Google used to host full-size versions of the images... and I had bypassed a few paywalls with that. That bypass might have impact on some artists' and photographers' business. Nintendo's product is more complex than images alone. So long as Bulbapedia's use is extremely non-competitive, (indeed, it's symbiotic with Nintendo's business), it does looks solid. Like the difference between reusing a high-res photo of a product's box art on another product vs. in a review of that product.